# Beginning Greasemonkey Help: Modifying Page Source Code?

Tags: greasemonkey

I'm quite new to Greasemonkey so bear with me. I'm trying to create a script that modifies the value of an ID of a webpage, and then enters a word into a textbox ID and presses submit.
How would I go about doing this? What code would I use?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Learn about Greasemonkey by:

1. Examining the [introduction](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Main_Page) and [tutorials](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Tutorials).
2. Inspect the code of GM scripts that are similar to what you want to do.  You can [find a mess of useful scripts at userscripts.org](http://userscripts.org/).

---

In general, beginner's guides are not encouraged at StackOverflow.  The [beginners-guide](/questions/tagged/beginners-guide) tag is not allowed to be used, and the [beginner](/questions/tagged/beginner) tag was ruthlessly "disappeared", for example.

---

Re:

> "How would I go about doing this? What code would I use?"

If you want us to write code from scratch for you**, then you must provide more detail and/or show some evidence of effort.
In this case, **link to the page your GM script will modify.**  Or, at the very least, post a sufficiently complete code snippet of the page and list exactly how you want it modified.

**Note that such requests rarely find much traction at SO.  This site is for programmers helping other programmers.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know jQuery?
It is easy to learn, easy to handle and easy to implement into Greasemonkey!

Just add

```
// @require       http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js
```

to the metadata of your script and code like you normally would with jQuery, except that you have GM_* commands to execute commands usual javascript is restricted.